# Spring hibernate transactional removing entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm, transactions

I have Spring MVC application divided on layers. One of them is Service and here's one of the methods

```
@Transactional
public boolean deleteProject(long id){
    Project project = projectDAO.read(id);
    taskDAO.deleteAllByProject(project);
    projectDAO.delete(project);
    return true;
}
```

It deletes tasks, but project remains in the db (with no error or exception). I didnt use @Transactional in repository classes.

Here's my Spring config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<bean id="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/automate" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="ru.jeak.keep" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="connection.pool_size">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">test</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userHibernateDAO" class="ru.jeak.keep.repository.hibernate.UserHibernateDAO" />
<bean id="projectHibernateDAO" class="ru.jeak.keep.repository.hibernate.ProjectHibernateDAO" />
<bean id="taskHibernateDAO" class="ru.jeak.keep.repository.hibernate.TaskHibernateDAO" />
```

UPDATE

I added persistence @Transactional to DAO class and it works now. But Im still confused why Spring did not do the rollback of deleting tasks after failure of deleting project

Comment: Can you paste your ProjectDAO delete method?

Comment: thats just hibernate's   getSession().delete(t);

Comment: Do you see the 'delete from project' query in the log? You should not need the @Transactional in the repositories.

Comment: Method got invoked but no sql output for project table

Comment: Can you try to reload the project before deleting it? After deleting tasks.